# Duplicate in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Angular doesn't allow to have duplicate elements in an array declared in ng-repeat as explained [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes).

But what if I temporarily have a dup in my function (because I'm reordering the array) and when the function returns there's no dup? will that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have read your link carefully.

You can have duplicate keys, you just have to add a 'track by'.

example to use "track by"

```
 ng-repeat="message in messages track by $index"
```

Also, if you order your list inside your controller and have sometimes a duplicate, it's not that bad.

Your controller will execute all his code, and when it will have finished, angular will trigger its `$digest`, where he will evaluate the new values inside the scope.

Comment: I read the link and saw it mentions to use 'track by $index'. My questions is if it's ok to have duplicates temporarily in the function before I return.